# tableau filter value based on the aggregated columns

Tags: tableau-desktop

[image]

I have my table looks like this.
I want to filter out those domains that all three variants are bigger than 0.
what should I do?

Thanks in advance

The aggregated number in table is got by countd another field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field which will return a boolean and then filter it:

To create a calculated field that returns a boolean value indicating whether three measure values are greater than 0 in Tableau, you can modify the previous formula as follows:

```
[Measure 1] > 0 AND [Measure 2] > 0 AND [Measure 3] > 0
```

Replace [Measure 1], [Measure 2], and [Measure 3] with the actual names of your measure fields. This calculated field will evaluate to True if all three measures are greater than 0 and False otherwise.

Now, you can use this calculated field in your analysis by dragging and dropping it onto your worksheet. It will display True or False for each data point based on the evaluation result.